# How can I send only a string value as the parameter in a POST network call using Alamofire?

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

So lets say instead of this,

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "settings":
        [
            "username" : UILabel.text,
            "password": textField.text,
        ],
]

Alamofire.request("myURL", method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding:)
.responseJSON { response in
print(response)
}
```

I would like to know if I could send only a string as the parameter like this,

```
let parameter: String
parameter = "SampleString"

Alamofire.request("myURL", method: .post, parameters: parameter).responseJSON{ response in 
print(response)
}
```

Comment: A string itself cannot be used as a parameter. It should have key-value. Why do you want to send a single string?

Comment: For example if I use built in Networking in iOS,
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.example.com")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = parameter
How to do the same using Alamofire?

Comment: In that example You simply dont send any parameter at all. In alamofire send params: nil and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var params = "{\"username\": \"\(UILabel.text)\"}"
Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters:[params]).responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your parameters always need to be of type dictionary, so that you have a key,value pair.

If you simply want to have one key, you can do this:

```
let parameter = ["parameterName": parameterValue]
```

Hope that helps!